# Loop through rows in table to access custom textfields in cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableviewcontroller in which I have a custom cell with a label and a textview :

```
class ContactInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var contactType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactValue: UITextField!
}
```

The datasource for this table is dynamic. What I'm looking to do is convert each row of the table into a dictionary `[contactType: contactValue]` but I'm not sure how to go about it. 
Do I need to attach some type of identifier to the textfield? Or do I loop through all of the rows of the table and construct the dictionary?

Comment: There is no reason to loop through the rows. Your data model should already have all of the data.

Comment: But I plan on editing the data, well the textfield values and I'm sending that dict somewhere

Comment: You posted a comment in the answer below: "My question is those text fields are editable and when I change the data in those fields and then hit save, I want to update the datasource"; I think that's the real question and probably your approach is wrong, you should probably edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: Well, thats kinda sorta my question, but the posted question is still valid, and the one I'm looking to find an answer to. I not looking to update the datasource per se, looking to get those new values along with the label data... I'm all ears though if you've got the right approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have your data source, which would have that array of dictionaries, say that array was called `contactDictArray`

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you would set the two cell properties `contactCell.contactType.text` and `contactCell.contactValue.text` to the information from the dictionary array at the cell index.

`dataSource.contactDictArray[indexPath.row]` would give you something like `["contactType": "mobile", "contactValue": "whateverInfoHere"]`

In order to capture the information from the textfield when it is edited, you would put the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
contactCell.contactValue.delegate = self
contactCell.contactValue.tag = indexPath.row
```

And you would add the UITextFieldDelegate at the top of your view controller class and add whatever delegate methods from the text field delegate that you need. In this case they might be `textFieldDidBeginEditing` or `textFieldDidEndEditing`, and then capture the information for the cell textfield from there.

In `textFieldDidEndEditing` and `textFieldShouldEndEditing` you could put the following code:

```
let contactArrayIndex = textField.tag
var contactDict = contactDictArray[contactArrayIndex]
//access info in textField 
//put code here to update the info for the dictionary in your array or to save that info in a dictionary property or whatever you need to do
```

When the save button is tapped, instead of doing resign first responder, you would do something to retrieve that data that you have saved in a property on your data model or your view controller.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: thank you, I did have that part worked out. My question is those text fields are editable and when I change the data in those fields and then hit save, I want to update the datasource

Comment: In that case you need to use the textfield delegate methods. I will update my answer.

Comment: One more question: is there a save button on the cell that they are clicking to save the info in the textfield? Or are you just saving the info when they are done typing in the textfield

Comment: No, a single save in the navbar. The way I see the save action working is that it should resignFirstResponder() on all textfields and save a dict of the type: value. I figure I would need to loop thru the table to achieve this, hence the question

Comment: Updated to answer what I think you are asking. Let me know if I am still misunderstanding.

Comment: aha, tag is the identifier, let me try this

Comment: yep, worked like a charm. thanks very much, I learned something

Comment: Thank you so it worked for me, @KaylaGalway can you have a look at this question!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer to my question did not utilize a looping thru the table, I did manage to figure out a way to do it should anyone coming to this question be interested.

```
        for case let rowView in self.tableView.subviews {
            for case let tableviewCell as ContactInfoTableViewCell in rowView.subviews {
                tableviewCell.contactValue.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
```